# Array with levels - each level has values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array that has multiple levels and multiple values on each level. It needs to look something like this:

- Value 1 level 1

  - Value 1 level 2

    - Value 1 level 3
  - Value 2 level 2
- Value 2 level 1

How can I put something like this in an array?

Comment: Use             _Object_ not array

Answer (score 0):

You can make each level as a new array.

```
var myArray = new Array("Value 1 level 1", "Value 2 level 1");
myArray['Value 1 level 1'] = new Array("Value 1 level 2", "Value 2 level 2");
myArray['Value 2 level 2'] = new Array("Value 1 level 3");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of objects like the below structure

```
var value=
{
 value1level1:
 {
value1level2:
   {
  value1level3:'somevalue'
   }
 }
};
var parentObj=[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON structure like this:

```
[
   {
      "node":{
         "Value 1":"level 1"
      },
      "children":[
         {
            "node":{
               "Value1":"level 2"
            },
            "children":[
               {
                  "node":{
                     "Value1":"level 3"
                  },
                  "children":[

                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "node":{
         "Value 2":"level 1"
      },
      "children":[

      ]
   }
]
```